# Indexing does not include PDF content

Tags: search, crawling, pdf

I am trying to get search (indexing) to include the content of PDF files. I have followed the guide from here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927675. I have also double-checked that the GUID (CLSID) is correct, that "pdf" has been added to File types, however content inside PDF files is still not being crawled.

This is using the latest Acrobat Reader (10) installed on the server (it's a single-server farm).

The server is Windows Server 2008 R2 (64-bit) and the installation is a WSS with Search Server 2008 Express. I am using the standard Acrobat installation, but I heard mention of a 64-bit PDF iFilter - can this be the cause or should the normal 32-bit filter work just fine as well?

Basically, I need to know what I can do to get the indexing to include PDF content.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you see the note about not idexing pdfs that were already on the server when installing the IFilters? Files will only be indexed if they have changed since the last crawl. (To be sure you can start a new full crawl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the 64-bit IFilter if your WSS/MSSX is 64-bit, otherwise 32 bit is the one to use.

You cannot just install the reader on the server (which I do not think you should do at all - there are currently no more unsecure product than Acrobat Reader!).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you installed "Acrobat Reader 10". What you need to install is an iFilter. You can choose between different available iFilter, but when you want to stick with Adobe you need this one here:

http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=4025